# The Sequence of query result in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Here is table named commonprofit:

```
name    date    turnover
1   2011/12 42359
1   2010/12 32863
1   2009/12 24293
1   2008/12 16436
1   2007/12 15442
2   2011/12 91634
2   2010/12 58410
2   2009/12 50668
2   2008/12 54297
3   2009/12 12352
3   2008/12 12352
3   2007/12 14226


select  name,max(date)  as date, turnover  from commonprofit  group  by name
union 
select  name,min(date) as date,turnover  from commonprofit    group  by name;
```

The reslut is

```
name|date|turnover
00001|2007/12|15442
00001|2011/12|42359
00002|2008/12|54297
00002|2011/12|91634
00003|2007/12|14226
00003|2009/12|12352
```

Why the result is not the following:

```
name|date|turnover
00001|2011/12|42359
00002|2011/12|91634
00003|2009/12|12352
00001|2007/12|15442
00002|2008/12|54297
00003|2007/12|14226
```

I  want to know the reason why the sequence is not what i want in the sqlite query?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific order you must provide an `order by` clause. E.g.,

```
select o, name, date, turnover from
(
  select  'x' as o, name, max(date) as date, turnover from commonprofit group  by name
  union 
  select  'n' as o, name, min(date) as date, turnover from commonprofit group  by name
)
order by o desc, name;

x|1|2011/12|42359
x|2|2011/12|91634
x|3|2009/12|12352
n|1|2007/12|15442
n|2|2008/12|54297
n|3|2007/12|14226
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `UNION` removes records that are duplicated in its subqueries.
To make finding duplicates easier, SQLite sorts the result.

To avoid this step, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.
(This implies that if there is a `name` with only one `date`, it will appear twice.)